# Using boost geometry intersection with linestring and polygon

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

I'm using `boost::geometry::intersection` with `boost::geometry::model::linestring` and `boost::geometry::model::polygon` in an application where it gets called frequently, and profiling shows that it's the most expensive part of the function it's in.

What I'm actually trying to learn is if the polygon lies between the endpoints of the linestring:
Let's posit that we have points `p1` and `p2` and a polygon `pg` all in the same plane.  We construct a `linestring ls` from `p1` and `p2`.  I consider that `pg` lies between `p1` and `p2` if `intersection(ls, pg, vp)` populates its 3rd argument (`vector<point>&`) with two `points`, neither of which is equal to either `p1` or `p2`.

I'm wondering if there's a smarter/less expensive way of answering that question?

Comment: What does it mean for the polygon to "lie between the endpoints"? Can you give examples or a rigorous definition?

Comment: So, [this](https://i.imgur.com/eJpI2Dz.png) would match the criteria? And [this](https://i.imgur.com/PWYm6SB.png) wouldn't? https://imgur.com/a/utAjTy0

Comment: In my question, I didn't enumerate all the special cases that I care about,  for fear of making it unreadable. What I'm actually trying to determine is if p2 is visible from p1. So, both of your cases would represent situations where the polygon was obscuring p2.

Comment: I've found that if I add an explicit strategy (`strategy::intersection::cartesian_segments<>()`) as an argument to `intersection()`, I get a slight improvement in speed. For what it's worth.

Comment: This is probably a very wellknown task in graphics progamming. Especially if one of the points would stay relatively stationary across queries, it seems to me that there should be optimized representations of the scene to gain a lot of speed. No expert here, I'd ask on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ I think the task is called occlusion culling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination#Occlusion_culling.

Comment: We've been working from "Computational Geometry", by de Berg et al. The pseudo-code I've been adapting is pretty explicit in some places and pretty vague in others. Boost geometry was chosen as a framework because its abstractions seemed to match the problem domain reasonably well. Thanks for the advice about the sister site - I'll pay it a visit.